# Mobile App Event Tracking not Triggering Journey [iOS SDK]

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush-ios, sdk

There is a similar question about this but it does not have helpful answer to solve my problem.

So I registered an event and set that event in the journey builder to send push notification once i have triggered the event.

This is the sample log that my app sends when i tried triggering the event, being **Connection Error** as the event i am trying to trigger. As i have mentioned, I have registered this event and created a journey builder when this event happened.

**2022-04-08 01:30:22.620487+0900 Luna[15983:967597] [module] log: `No triggers for key Connection Error in event <CustomEvent: 0x280496fe0>` file: `MarketingCloudSDKEvent.m` line: `line: 923`**

any ideas how to debug?

Comment: Open a support case.

Comment: Hey, did you find any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question to support and was told to upgrade to Marketing Cloud SDK v8 which fixed the issue.